# Hadoop 2.2.0 on Windows: Job is Successful but just outputs the input file

Tags: java, windows, hadoop, mapreduce

I downloaded the source code for Hadoop 2.2.0 and all of the relevant dependencies and built it/installed it/configured it. Note that I built it using MinGW from Git rather than Cygwin, if that matters.

I am running a job but the only output that I get is the input file. Logging from my mapper or reducer is not working, either - in fact, I don't even know how to get Hadoop to tell me if it is running my specific class implementation.

Mapper code:

```
package org.test.dummy;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DummyMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>{
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyMapper.class);
  private Text character = new Text();
  private LongWritable one = new LongWritable(1);

  /** @see org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper#map(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.Context) */
  @Override
  protected void map(
    LongWritable id, 
    Text line, 
    org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, LongWritable>.Context context) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException 
  {
    log.info("Starting Dummy mapper");
    for(char c : line.toString().toCharArray()) {
      this.character.set(Character.toString(c));
      context.write(this.character, this.one);
    }
  }
}
```

Reducer code:

```
package org.test.dummy;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class DummyReducer extends Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable> {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DummyReducer.class);
  private LongWritable count = new LongWritable(0);

  /** @see org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer#reduce(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Iterable, org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer.Context) */
  @Override
  protected void reduce(
      Text character, 
      Iterable<LongWritable> tickMarks, 
      org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer<Text, LongWritable, Text, LongWritable>.Context context) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException 
  {
    log.info("Starting Dummy reducer");
    long count = 0;
    for(@SuppressWarnings("unused") LongWritable tick : tickMarks) count++;
    this.count.set(count);
    context.write(character, this.count);
  }
}
```

Driver code:

```
package org.test.dummy;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

public class Dummy {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Dummy.class);

  /** @param args */
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      log.info("Starting Dummy driver");
      Job job = Job.getInstance(new Configuration(), "dummy-job");
      job.setJarByClass(Dummy.class);
      job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
      job.setOutputValueClass(LongWritable.class);
      job.setMapperClass(DummyMapper.class);
      job.setReducerClass(DummyReducer.class);
      job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
      job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
      FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
      FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
      boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true) ;
      System.exit(success ? 0 : 1);
    } catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace(System.err);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
}
```

Maven snippet in POM to set the driver class for Hadoop, so that the main class doesn't need to be set on the command line:

```
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>org.test.Dummy</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Process to scrub clean and reset my Hadoop environment to guarantee clean execution (note that I am using MinGW that comes with Git for my Unix commands):

```
SET JAVA_HOME=c:\jdk7
SET HADOOP_HOME=c:\hadoop
rmdir c:\tmp /S /Q
rmdir %HADOOP_HOME%\data /S/Q
mkdir %HADOOP_HOME%\data\dfs
mkdir %HADOOP_HOME%\data\dfs\namenode
mkdir %HADOOP_HOME%\data\dfs\datanode
call %HADOOP_HOME%\bin\hdfs namenode -format
call %HADOOP_HOME%\sbin\start-dfs.cmd
call %HADOOP_HOME%\sbin\start-yarn.cmd
call hdfs dfs -mkdir /in
call bash -c "hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal ./src/test/resources/my-file.txt hdfs://localhost:9000/in"
call %HADOOP_HOME%\bin\yarn jar target\my-hadoop-job.jar /in/my-file.txt /out
call %HADOOP_HOME%\bin\hdfs dfs -ls -R /out
```

Here is the relevant output of this process:

```
Formatting using clusterid: CID-9d811b80-42cb-4cc6-aa0b-e84e349701d5
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.HostFileManager: read includes:
HostSet(
)
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.HostFileManager: read excludes:
HostSet(
)
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.DatanodeManager: dfs.block.invalidate.limit=1000
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map BlocksMap
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: 2.0% max memory = 888.9 MB
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^21 = 2097152 entries
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: dfs.block.access.token.enable=false
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: defaultReplication         = 1
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplication             = 512
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: minReplication             = 1
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: maxReplicationStreams      = 2
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: shouldCheckForEnoughRacks  = false
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: replicationRecheckInterval = 3000
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO blockmanagement.BlockManager: encryptDataTransfer        = false
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: fsOwner             = some.one (auth:SIMPLE)
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: supergroup          = supergroup
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: isPermissionEnabled = true
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: HA Enabled: false
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Append Enabled: true
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map INodeMap
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: 1.0% max memory = 888.9 MB
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^20 = 1048576 entries
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.NameNode: Caching file names occuring more than 10 times
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.threshold-pct = 0.9990000128746033
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.min.datanodes = 0
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: dfs.namenode.safemode.extension     = 30000
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache on namenode is enabled
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Retry cache will use 0.03 of total heap and retry cache entry expiry time is 600000 millis
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: Computing capacity for map Namenode Retry Cache
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory = 888.9 MB
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^15 = 32768 entries
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory \hadoop\data\dfs\namenode has been successfully formatted.
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSImage: Saving image file \hadoop\data\dfs\namenode\current\fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.FSImage: Image file \hadoop\data\dfs\namenode\current\fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 208 bytes saved in 0 seconds.
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 0
14/02/04 12:00:45 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at xxxxxxxxxxxxx
************************************************************/
....
14/02/04 12:31:31 INFO test.Dummy: Starting Dummy driver
14/02/04 12:31:33 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
14/02/04 12:31:33 WARN mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with
ToolRunner to remedy this.
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:1
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: user.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.user.name
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.map.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.map.class
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.reduce.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.reduce.class
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.inputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.inputformat.class
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapreduce.outputformat.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.outputformat.class
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO Configuration.deprecation: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1391509606870_0001
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO impl.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1391509606870_0001 to ResourceManager at /127.0.0.1:8032
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://localhost:8088/proxy/application_1391509606870_0001/
14/02/04 12:31:34 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1391509606870_0001
14/02/04 12:31:43 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1391509606870_0001 running in uber mode : false
14/02/04 12:31:43 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/02/04 12:31:50 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 0%
14/02/04 12:31:57 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 100% reduce 100%
14/02/04 12:31:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1391509606870_0001 completed successfully
14/02/04 12:31:58 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 43
        File System Counters
                FILE: Number of bytes read=1395
                FILE: Number of bytes written=133855
                FILE: Number of read operations=0
                FILE: Number of large read operations=0
                FILE: Number of write operations=0
                HDFS: Number of bytes read=1275
                HDFS: Number of bytes written=1243
                HDFS: Number of read operations=6
                HDFS: Number of large read operations=0
                HDFS: Number of write operations=2
        Job Counters
                Launched map tasks=1
                Launched reduce tasks=1
                Data-local map tasks=1
                Total time spent by all maps in occupied slots (ms)=4357
                Total time spent by all reduces in occupied slots (ms)=4717
        Map-Reduce Framework
                Map input records=24
                Map output records=24
                Map output bytes=1340
                Map output materialized bytes=1395
                Input split bytes=104
                Combine input records=0
                Combine output records=0
                Reduce input groups=24
                Reduce shuffle bytes=1395
                Reduce input records=24
                Reduce output records=24
                Spilled Records=48
                Shuffled Maps =1
                Failed Shuffles=0
                Merged Map outputs=1
                GC time elapsed (ms)=64
                CPU time spent (ms)=1184
                Physical memory (bytes) snapshot=397262848
                Virtual memory (bytes) snapshot=641183744
                Total committed heap usage (bytes)=334495744
        Shuffle Errors
                BAD_ID=0
                CONNECTION=0
                IO_ERROR=0
                WRONG_LENGTH=0
                WRONG_MAP=0
                WRONG_REDUCE=0
        File Input Format Counters
                Bytes Read=1171
        File Output Format Counters
                Bytes Written=1243
...
-rw-r--r--   1 some.one supergroup          0 2014-02-04 12:31 /out/_SUCCESS
-rw-r--r--   1 some.one supergroup       1243 2014-02-04 12:31 /out/part-r-00000
```

When I call `hdfs dfs -cat /out/part-r-00000`, though, I only get a copy of my input file.

The Hadoop job logs tell me nothing: stdout and stderr logs are 0 bytes; the syslog is 37+kb but I don't see anything informative in it. The only logging from my code that gets recorded is in the driver.

What am I doing wrong? (Besides relying on Hadoop in Windows....) My impression is that Hadoop is doing *something*, but it's not actually working.

In case it helps, here are my Hadoop configuration properties:

mapred-site.xml:

```
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
  <value>-Djava.awt.headless=true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.command-opts</name>
  <value>-Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx256m</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.app.mapreduce.am.admin-command-opts</name>
  <value>-Djava.awt.headless=true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>local</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.mapper.new-api</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.reducer.new-api</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.job.user.classpath.first</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>The maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.map.tasks</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>The default number of map tasks per job. Ignored when mapred.job.tracker is "local".</description>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name>
  <value>1</value>
  <description>The default number of reduce tasks per job.</description>
</property>
<!-- This right here is an AWFUL hack to work around an even more awful bug -->
<property>
  <name>mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir</name>
  <value>/out</value>
</property>
```

hdfs-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>dfs.replication</name>
  <value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
  <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/namenode</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
  <value>file:/hadoop/data/dfs/datanode</value>
</property>
```

yarn-site.xml:

```
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
 <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
  <value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
  <description>CLASSPATH for YARN applications. A comma-separated list of CLASSPATH entries</description>
  <name>yarn.application.classpath</name>
  <value>
      %HADOOP_HOME%\etc\hadoop,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\*,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\common\lib\*,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\*,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hdfs\lib\*,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\*,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\mapreduce\lib\*,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\*,
      %HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\yarn\lib\*
  </value>
</property>
```

core-site.xml:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
  <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
</property>
```

I have not been successful in finding anything online that helps. I've scoured StackOverflow, but haven't seen anything resembling my problem that I haven't already done. Any help would be great!

EDIT: I should note that my Mapper/Reducer run correctly in MRUnit.

Comment: Hmmm... Running this Hadoop job jar on a Hortonworks sandbox works fine. So it's got to be my Hadoop configuration - or the fact that I am trying to run on a local windows install...